# Adding ad code to my blogspot blog

Tags: html

I would like to add adcode to my blogger page where it have to show near first heading and in the center. I have found a way that it actually works, but what's troubling me is if i show ad in the center i cant show it near post heading, and if i show it near post heading i cant show it on center of the post.
here is the code i am using to show ads on center of the post, where i have to replace ''< data:post.body/>'' with following....

```
<div id='jobmiddlenew'> 
    <data:post.body/> </div> 
     <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'> 
       <style> #addcodemiddle{display: none;} </style> 
<div id='addcodemiddle'>Ad Code Here </div> 
  <script ='text/javascript'> var 
     str1=document.getElementById(&quot;jobmiddlenew&quot;).innerHTML; var 
      str2=str1.length; var str3=str2/2; var substr = str1.substring(str3, 
     str2); 
    var n = substr.search(&quot;&lt;br&gt;&quot;); if(n&lt;0) { n = 
  substr.indexOf('.'); if(n&lt;0) { n=0; } var firsthalf = str1.substring(0, 
   str3+n+1); var secondhalf = str1.substring(str3+n+1, str2); } else { var 
    firsthalf = str1.substring(0, str3+n+4); var secondhalf = 
     str1.substring(str3+n+4, str2); } var addcode=&quot;

<center>&quot;+document.getElementById(&quot;addcodemiddle&quot;)              
.innerHTML+&quot;</center><br/>&quot;; var 
  newbody=firsthalf+addcode+secondhalf; var 
   strnew=document.getElementsByClassName(&quot;post-body entry-
     content&quot;); strnew[0].innerHTML=newbody; 
   document.getElementById(&quot;addcodemiddle&quot;).innerHTML=&quot;&quot;; </script>
```

and here is the adcode i use to display ads near post headline, which i have to do same as the first one.

```
 <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
  <div id='ad-content' style="display:block;text-align: center">
   /ad code here
  </div></b:if>
  <div id='ad-target'><data:post.body/></div>
    <script ='text/javascript'>
      function insertAfter(addition,target) {
       var parent = target.parentNode;
   if (parent.lastChild == target) {
   parent.appendChild(addition);
  } else {
 parent.insertBefore(addition,target.nextSibling);
 }
}
 var adscont = document.getElementById(&quot;ad-content&quot;);
  var target = document.getElementById(&quot;ad-target&quot;);
   var linebreak = target.getElementsByTagName(&quot;h3&quot;);
  if (linebreak.length &gt; 0){
   insertAfter(adscont,linebreak[0]);
 }
  </script>
```

so i would like to know how can i place ad code on both places [Center of the post and Near post heading ] at the same time and show ads.